# Need help in crawling multiple web pages and to the next page from there using Scrapy in Python in a loop

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, scrapy, web-crawler

Currently I am crawling multiple web sites in a go and needed to crawl next page where the link to the next page will be obtained from the crawled site. So needed to crawl the next page of each page continuously. Note that the second page from each page have the same div contents.

### Spider.py

```
class UstodaySpider(scrapy.Spider):

name = 'usatoday'

start_urls = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India',
              'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USA
              ]

def parse(self, response):
    items = MynewsItem()
    print ("**********************************")
    print (type(response))
    print (response.url)

    all_section = response.css(' a.gnt_m_flm_a ')

    for quote in all_section:
        news_provider_id = '14'
        news_title = quote.css('a.gnt_m_flm_a').xpath("text()").extract()
        news_details = quote.css('a.gnt_m_flm_a').xpath("@data-c-br").extract()
        news_image = quote.css("img.gnt_m_flm_i").xpath("@data-gl-srcset").extract()
        news_page_url = quote.css('a.gnt_m_flm_a').xpath("@href").extract()


        items['news_provider_id'] = news_provider_id
        items['news_title'] = news_title
        items['news_details'] = news_details
        items['news_image'] = news_image
        items['news_page_url'] = news_page_url

    yield items
    next_page = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India' + str(news_page_url)
    print(next_page)
```

### Pipeline.py

```
import mysql
class MynewsPipeline(object):
 def __init__(self):
   self.create_connection()
    self.create_table()
 def create_connection(self):
    self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(

        host = 'localhost',
        user = 'root',
        password = '',
        database = 'mydb',
        port = '3306'
    )

    self.curr = self.conn.cursor()

 def create_table(self):

    self.curr.execute("""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS news_crawl_newsdetails""")
    self.curr.execute("""create table news_crawl_newsdetails(
                    news_provider_id text,
                    news_title text,
                    news_details text,
                    news_image text,
                    news_page_url text
                    )""" )

 def process_item(self, item, spider):
    self.store_db(item)
    return item
 def store_db(self,item):
    # print (item['news_title'][0])

     self.curr.execute("""insert into news_crawl_newsdetails (news_provider_id,news_title,news_details,news_image,news_page_url) values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""", (

        item['news_provider_id'],
        item['news_title'][0],
        item['news_details'][0],
        item['news_image'][0],
        item['news_page_url'][0]

    ))

    self.conn.commit()
```

### Items.py

```
import scrapy
class MynewsItem(scrapy.Item):
  news_provider_id = scrapy.Field()
  news_title = scrapy.Field()
  news_details = scrapy.Field()
  news_image = scrapy.Field()
  news_page_url = scrapy.Field()
  news_des = scrapy.Field()
  pass
```

Comment: Is that all code? Cause I cant see when you iterate start_urls

Comment: Yes, this is what we had. I worked for the first page but not able go to the next page

Comment: yield scrapy.Request(
                        next_page,
                        callback=self.parse
                    )

Comment: Tried this one also but not getting the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this approach:

you should locate next_page xpath . it could be a link or a button to the next page:

```
next_page = response.selector.xpath(--xpath expression--).extract_first()

if next_page is not None:
    next_page_link = response.urljoin(next_page)
    yield scrapy.Request(url = next_page_link, callback=self.parse)
```

this is what your parse function should look like

```
def parse(self, response):
    items = MynewsItem()
    print ("**********************************")
    print (type(response))
    print (response.url)

    all_section = response.css(' a.gnt_m_flm_a ')

    for quote in all_section:
        news_provider_id = '14'
        news_title = quote.css('a.gnt_m_flm_a').xpath("text()").extract()
        news_details = quote.css('a.gnt_m_flm_a').xpath("@data-c-br").extract()
        news_image = quote.css("img.gnt_m_flm_i").xpath("@data-gl-srcset").extract()
        news_page_url = quote.css('a.gnt_m_flm_a').xpath("@href").extract()


        items['news_provider_id'] = news_provider_id
        items['news_title'] = news_title
        items['news_details'] = news_details
        items['news_image'] = news_image
        items['news_page_url'] = news_page_url

     next_page = response.selector.xpath("").extract_first()

     if next_page is not None:
         next_page_link = response.urljoin(next_page)
         yield scrapy.Request(url= next_page_link, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort and response.

But showing Error:
DNS lookup failed: no results for hostname lookup:
www.en.wikipedia.orghttps.


Got any idea regarding why https is appending with the string. Also the style of the two pages are different is it the issue for the error.